# Facebook - Maximum iframe width?

Tags: facebook

> This question is obsolete.  [See
>   here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828293) for an updated
>   version.

---

Is there a maximum width an iframe Facebook application can be?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828293

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just played with it and to the pixel <del>758</del> 760 was the largest I could go with out a scroll bar.

Edit: As portman has pointed out I had forgotten about borders. Please upvote his answer.

Comment: You need to set frameborder="0". Otherwise you'll have 1px of border on all sides.

Comment: I just double checked and it's 758 instead of the documented 760 pixels.

I know what frameborder does. But I don't see how I can specify it since it's part of facebook.com not part of my application.

Comment: I imagine there should be a way to change it. I posted my answer ages ago but if I remember right I did try it out on my own.

Answer (score 36):

### 760 pixels

This line is here to achieve the minimum required characters in an answer.

Comment: Can I upvote this more than once please, StackOverflow? :p

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when using 760px though, I have often found you actually get a few less than they promise. I usually shoot for 740px to ensure I don't get any scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding public css style in application page and I got 760 px

```css
<style>
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: A better way to achieve a similar solution without destroying elements' defaults would be a reset css sheet.